# Bulk deletion of rules?

Tags: rules

I was testing with rules and now I got around 50 rules. Just wondering if Is there any way to bulk delete rules and components

Comment: i would connect to the db and delete from that table. always test your query with a select statement first.

Comment: I thought of this, but there are 6 rules related tables, and I would need to search for any dependencies in each table.

Comment: take a look at how the module deletes the entry. then you can simply add AND/OR in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The rules module provides a function called [`rules_config_delete()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_config_delete/7).

You can call this with an array of rules ids to delete multiple rules in one go:

```
rules_config_delete(array(3, 4, 5, 6));
```